# postscript to pdf conversion not retaining font

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I have converted the pdf file to postscript using Ghostscript. When I print it, it changed the font which I used in PDF. why it's not retaining fonts?. Even, I have tried to convert ps to pdf again, I could see, font got changed in a few places. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Is the font visually changing or just the name?  Is the font embedded in the PDF?

Ghostscript will substitute a font if it is not embedded and it does not have access to it.  Sometimes the substituted font is not a great choice.

If you run it on a command line, it should list the substitutions being made.